# Is there a way to get webhook/trigger event for Gmail group member addition and removal?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-admin-sdk, google-workspace, google-workspace-add-ons

I'm interested to know if Google workspace admin API or AppScript provides any kind of webhook or trigger when a member is added or removed from a particular group. Currently, I can think of a solution to poll the current members but it is inefficient.
Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/push

Comment: @TheAddonDepot thank you for the help. I'll try this out.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the Admin Reports API can send "enterprise_groups" events in push notifications.

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/appendix/activity/groups-enterprise

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/push

You can customise the push request to receive events from a single group.